# How to attach added custom html to ace editor lines using addDynamicMarker?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I want to create a collaborative text editor using [ACE Editor](https://ace.c9.io). I found out that I should use `addDynamicMarker` to add other user's cursor into the editor, that you can find it's documentation [here](https://ace.c9.io/api/edit_session.html#EditSession.addDynamicMarker).

With the following snippet code, I can add remotely connected user's cursor into the editor. but I don't know how attach it to the lines. I mean, if you enter in first row, you will see that everything will shift down by the number of lines that you entered, but dynamic cursors (`RED remote cursor`) will stick to their position:

```js
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
  
 var label = "I am red remote cursor :)";
 
    var marker_element = document.createElement("div");
    var cursor_element = document.createElement("div");
    cursor_element.className = "ace-multi-cursor";
    cursor_element.style.background = "red";
    marker_element.append(cursor_element);

    var tooltip_element = document.createElement("div");
    tooltip_element.className = "ace-multi-cursor-tooltip";
    tooltip_element.style.background = "red";
    tooltip_element.style.opacity = "1";
    tooltip_element.innerHTML = label;
    marker_element.append(tooltip_element);
 
 var buildDom = ace.require("ace/lib/dom").buildDom
 editor.session.addDynamicMarker({
  contentNode: null,
  update: function(_, layer, session, config) {
   var screen_position = editor.session.documentToScreenPosition(6, 6);

   var top = layer.$getTop(screen_position.row, config);
   var left = layer.$padding + screen_position.column * config.characterWidth;
   var height = config.lineHeight;

   var cursor_top = top + 2;
   var cursor_height = height - 3;
   var cursor_left = left;
   var cursor_width = 2;
   
   cursor_element.style.height = `${cursor_height}px`;
   cursor_element.style.width = `${cursor_width}px`;
   cursor_element.style.top = `${cursor_top}px`;
   cursor_element.style.left = `${cursor_left}px`;

   let toolTipTop = cursor_top - height;
   if (toolTipTop < 5) {
     toolTipTop = cursor_top + height - 1;
   }

   const toolTipLeft = cursor_left;
   tooltip_element.style.top = `${toolTipTop - 2}px`;
   tooltip_element.style.left = `${toolTipLeft - 2}px`;

   // Remove the content node from whatever parent it might have now
   // and add it to the new parent node.
   marker_element.remove();
   layer.elt("remote-cursor", "");
   const parentNode = layer.element.childNodes[layer.i - 1] || layer.element.lastChild;
   parentNode.appendChild(marker_element);
  }
 }, true);
```

```css
#editor {
 /*height: 150px;*/
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.other_user_selection {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 6;
}

.other_user_selection.blue {
 background-color: blue;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

/*ACE Collab ext*/
.ace-multi-cursor {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.ace-multi-cursor-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.ace-multi-selection {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.ace-radar-view {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 6px;
}

.ace-radar-view-scroll-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: double;
  border-width: 3px;
}

.ace-radar-view-cursor-indicator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.ace-radar-view-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;

  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;

  margin-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.7/ace.js" integrity="sha256-C7DTYRJLG+B/VEzHGeoPMw699nsTQYPAXHKXZb+q04E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor">
function foo(items) {
    var x = items * items;
    return x;
}

var test = foo(2);

console.log(test); //should be 4

console.log(foo(1)); //should be 1

console.log(foo(3)); //should be 9
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I can try to create a complicated function to listen to the editor's changes and if there is new line, update the cursor's position, but I thought maybe ACE editor has some better internal functions for it.

Thanks in advance for any clue or any guide.

Answer (score 1):

Ace has two api helping to update cursor positions, for ranges there is rangelist which is used by the collab cursor implementation in cloud9 https://github.com/c9/core/blob/c4d1c59dc8d6619bdca3dbe740291cd5cd26352c/plugins/c9.ide.collab/cursor_layer.js#L196 and for single points there is anchor

```
var anchor = editor.session.doc.createAnchor(10, 10)
editor.session.insert({row: 0, column: 0}, "\n")
anchor.getPosition().row == 11
```

it is important to call `anchor.detach()` when it is not needed anymore, otherwise it will stay attached to document and won't be collected.